# Test if application is running in a jar file in Java

Tags: java, resources

So i've been doing some research and have found a hackish solution to my problem, which is this: How do I determine if the resource that I am loading within the source folder is being extracted from a jar file, or is in the build directories that Netbeans autoconfigs?

Here's what I have found so far: 
I noticed if i load a file that is within the project with

```
File file = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(somefile.txt);
```

the call to

```
System.out.println(File.getPath());
```

will output something like this to the console:

```
jar:path/to/file.txt
```

in which I can test with the String function

```
path.contains("jar");
```

to get a boolean that seems to tell me if the resource is within a jar file.

My question I guess is if there is a better solution to this, or if this is the preferred way to do this?

I am open to suggestions or any answers

Comment: The preferred way is not having to care where the resource comes from. The ability to inject configuration by adding to the classpath at runtime is a valuable tool, for example. Can you explain more why this distinction is important for your application?

Comment: So the user can use the resources within the jar file, or their own images. I am making a demo that allows the user to create their own rpg character from the resources inside the jar. Or specify other character sprites if they want. I could make two different methods, this just makes it a one size fits all solution..

Comment: Then you would look at the user-specified location, and if it is found, use it. Otherwise use the built-in resource. (Or a bit more tricky, just load from classpath and ask the user to put their stuff on the classpath first, but I'd not do that, as it is not especially userfriendly). Whatever code makes use of the image should not need to care, I think.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I still am curious if there is any built in functions in java that could test this. I am assuming now that there is no need for it though, from what you are saying. I am trying to make it as user friendly as possible so I probably will go with your approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassLoader.getResource(String)` returns an URL, no File. Instead of converting that to a string and using a String.contains() call, you should check what the `getProtocol()`method returns:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/somefile.txt");
if(null != url){    
    System.out.println(url.getProtocol());
}
```